# Trying to print lines with alpha, special and numeric characters via regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to determine the best way to search a file with python for a string such as this:

```
BusID = 9876
```

Of course 9876 could be any 4 digit string e.g., 1234, 5678, 9999, etc. And `BusID` should always be part of the line.

The file `sample_file_with_digits.txt` for demonstration purposes would look like this:

```
12
123
1234
2345 foo 
BusID = 3456 
foo BusID = 9876
```

I know in bash or powershell I can use this regex to find any 4 digit number in the file (if wrapped in spaces) with a regex like this: `(?<!\S)[0-9]{4}(?!\S)`.

But I have to ensure that any 4 digit number I find is on the same line as BusID.  I am struggling figuring out how to approach this with python:

I opened up a file in Jupyter notebook and added the following cells and can read the file:

```
import re
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\frank\\Documents\\sample_file_with_digits.txt")
myfile1.read()
```

I have been trying to determine how I might use `re.findall` or `re.compile` to print the lines in this file like these:

```
BusID = 3456 
foo BusID = 9876
```

Comment: `\bBusID\s+=\s+\d{4}(?!\S)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first compile the regex statement and then use `search` to lookup the string.

```
import re

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    pat = re.compile('BusID = [0-9]{4}(?![0-9])')
    for line in f:
        if(pat.search(line) is not None):
            print(line.strip())
```

Edit: A negative lookahead is added to the regex as @Wiktor Stribiżew suggested

Comment: Probably, a lookahead would help here since OP needs to get 4-digit numbers only, `'BusID = [0-9]{4}(?![0-9])'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks. You are right. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through each line in the file, checking if the line contains "BusID". If it does, then check for a 4-digit number. If we find one, output the whole line.

```
import re
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\frank\\Documents\\sample_file_with_digits.txt")
# read in the file as a list of lines
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "BusID" in line and re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', line) is not None:
        # print the line
        print(line)
```

Comment: I am not getting any output with this for some reason. I'll have to look into it.